# Display a & in a menuitem or menustrip

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms, menuitem

I have a menu item that needs to be formated like This & That, but the & is converted to an underscore.  Is there an escape character to actually be able to display the &?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just double the '&' character

```
menuItem.Text = "Foo && Bar";
```

Answer (score 7):

Either use a double ampersand (but that will change the string literal) or you should be able to set the UseMnemonic property of the menuitem to false.